# How to extract map coordinates from json and assign to variable

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

Please help extract map coordinates from Json object and assign them into variable with format like below.Currently i have a google map with lines joining the markets using the coordinates from the variable below ,I need help to populate the variable "flightPlanCoordinates" dynamically from Json API?

```
    var flightPlanCoordinates = [
      {lat: 19.1759668, lng: 72.79504659999998},
      {lat: 19.0883595, lng: 72.82652380000002},
      {lat: 18.9542149, lng: 72.81203529999993},
      {lat: 18.979006, lng: 72.83388300000001},
      {lat:19.2147067, lng: 72.91062020000004}
    ];
```

Here is the Json object:

```
[
{
    "title": 'Aksa Beach',
    "lat": '19.1759668',
    "lng": '72.79504659999998',
    "description": 'Aksa Beach is a popular beach and a vacation spot in Aksa village at Malad, Mumbai.'
},
{
    "title": 'Juhu Beach',
    "lat": '19.0883595',
    "lng": '72.82652380000002',
    "description": 'Juhu Beach is one of favorite tourist attractions situated in Mumbai.'
},
{
    "title": 'Girgaum Beach',
    "lat": '18.9542149',
    "lng": '72.81203529999993',
    "description": 'Girgaum Beach commonly known as just Chaupati is one of the most famous public beaches in Mumbai.'
},
{
    "title": 'Jijamata Udyan',
    "lat": '18.979006',
    "lng": '72.83388300000001',
    "description": 'Jijamata Udyan is situated near Byculla station is famous as Mumbai (Bombay) Zoo.'
},
{
    "title": 'Sanjay Gandhi National Park',
    "lat": '19.2147067',
    "lng": '72.91062020000004',
    "description": 'Sanjay Gandhi National Park is a large protected area in the northern part of Mumbai city.'
}
];
```

Here is the entire code but the function getJsonstring() does not retun array as i need ,Please advise ?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        //Array of JSON objects.
        var markers = [
        {
            "title": 'Aksa Beach',
            "lat": '19.1759668',
            "lng": '72.79504659999998',
            "description": 'Aksa Beach is a popular beach and a vacation spot in Aksa village at Malad, Mumbai.'
        },
        {
            "title": 'Juhu Beach',
            "lat": '19.0883595',
            "lng": '72.82652380000002',
            "description": 'Juhu Beach is one of favorite tourist attractions situated in Mumbai.'
        },
        {
            "title": 'Girgaum Beach',
            "lat": '18.9542149',
            "lng": '72.81203529999993',
            "description": 'Girgaum Beach commonly known as just Chaupati is one of the most famous public beaches in Mumbai.'
        },
        {
            "title": 'Jijamata Udyan',
            "lat": '18.979006',
            "lng": '72.83388300000001',
            "description": 'Jijamata Udyan is situated near Byculla station is famous as Mumbai (Bombay) Zoo.'
        },
        {
            "title": 'Sanjay Gandhi National Park',
            "lat": '19.2147067',
            "lng": '72.91062020000004',
            "description": 'Sanjay Gandhi National Park is a large protected area in the northern part of Mumbai city.'
        }
        ];
        window.onload = function () {
            LoadMap();
        }
           function LoadMap() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);

            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var data = markers[i]
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                alert(myLatlng);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: data.title,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                });


                (function (marker, data) {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                        infoWindow.setContent("<div style = 'width:200px;min-height:40px'>" + data.description + "</div>");
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                })(marker, data);
                latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
            }
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
            map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

            var flightPlanCoordinates = getJsonString();
            alert(flightPlanCoordinates);
            var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
              path: flightPlanCoordinates,
              geodesic: true,
              strokeColor: '#FF0000',
              strokeOpacity: 1.0,
              strokeWeight: 2
            });

            flightPath.setMap(map);


            function getJsonString(){
                        for (var j = 0; j < markers.length; j++) {
                            var data = markers[j]
                            var jsonString = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);    

                       return jsonString;
            }
            }

    }
</script>
  </head>
<body >
<div id="dvMap" style="width: 900px; height: 800px">
</div>
 <div id="footer">
            <div class="centre-container">
            <div id="inner">
                                    </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

  </body>
```

Comment: Could you show some code for how you obtain the JSON API? If you're obtaining it like `...function(response){`then you're able to do inside of this parenthesis `var flightPlanCoordinates = response` as `response` will be your returned object.

Comment: Your function getJsonString is full of mistakes. It starts with when you create `var j`, but then  you refer to `i` not `j` through the rest of the function. It has a loop to go over all the markers, but it will return on the first iteration of that loop.  It's called getJsonString but it returns a Marker object.

Comment: @duncan i corrected the i and j mistake, do you have an idea how i cam modify the function to return an array like the one at the first block of code in my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is already parsing the JSON to create the markers.  Push those coordinates into an array to use as a path for the Polyline.

```
var flightPathCoords = [];
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  var data = markers[i]
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
  flightPathCoords.push(myLatlng);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: data.title,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
  });
// snip

var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: flightPathCoords,
  geodesic: true,
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  strokeWeight: 2
});
flightPath.setMap(map);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/1pb0onps/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function LoadMap() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
  var flightPathCoords = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var data = markers[i]
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
    flightPathCoords.push(myLatlng);
    // alert(myLatlng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: data.title,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });

    (function(marker, data) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
        infoWindow.setContent("<div style = 'width:200px;min-height:40px'>" + data.description + "</div>");
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    })(marker, data);
    latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
  }
  map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
  map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPathCoords,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}
//Array of JSON objects.
var markers = [{
  "title": 'Aksa Beach',
  "lat": '19.1759668',
  "lng": '72.79504659999998',
  "description": 'Aksa Beach is a popular beach and a vacation spot in Aksa village at Malad, Mumbai.'
}, {
  "title": 'Juhu Beach',
  "lat": '19.0883595',
  "lng": '72.82652380000002',
  "description": 'Juhu Beach is one of favorite tourist attractions situated in Mumbai.'
}, {
  "title": 'Girgaum Beach',
  "lat": '18.9542149',
  "lng": '72.81203529999993',
  "description": 'Girgaum Beach commonly known as just Chaupati is one of the most famous public beaches in Mumbai.'
}, {
  "title": 'Jijamata Udyan',
  "lat": '18.979006',
  "lng": '72.83388300000001',
  "description": 'Jijamata Udyan is situated near Byculla station is famous as Mumbai (Bombay) Zoo.'
}, {
  "title": 'Sanjay Gandhi National Park',
  "lat": '19.2147067',
  "lng": '72.91062020000004',
  "description": 'Sanjay Gandhi National Park is a large protected area in the northern part of Mumbai city.'
}];
window.onload = function() {
  LoadMap();
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#dvMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="dvMap">
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <div class="centre-container">
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one works pefectly Thank you, do you know how i can add label on those markers ?  @geocodezip

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-labels

Comment: ,I tried that one but instead of adding the label inside the marker it add the label below the marker. I need to add the lable inside like [link](http://jsfiddle.net/LLd4drvx/290/)

Comment: Did you review the documentation on how to control the position of the label?  In any case that is another/new question.

Answer (score 1):

I will run this with you hardcoded (I'm assuming you already have a JSON object to connect to google from their docs.)

**Step 1:**

insert json string into var with a JSON.parse function.

```
jsonString = JSON.parse('[
{
    "title": 'Aksa Beach',
    "lat": '19.1759668',
    "lng": '72.79504659999998',
    "description": 'Aksa Beach is a popular beach and a vacation spot in Aksa village at Malad, Mumbai.'
},
{
    "title": 'Juhu Beach',
    "lat": '19.0883595',
    "lng": '72.82652380000002',
    "description": 'Juhu Beach is one of favorite tourist attractions situated in Mumbai.'
},
{
    "title": 'Girgaum Beach',
    "lat": '18.9542149',
    "lng": '72.81203529999993',
    "description": 'Girgaum Beach commonly known as just Chaupati is one of the most famous public beaches in Mumbai.'
},
{
    "title": 'Jijamata Udyan',
    "lat": '18.979006',
    "lng": '72.83388300000001',
    "description": 'Jijamata Udyan is situated near Byculla station is famous as Mumbai (Bombay) Zoo.'
},
{
    "title": 'Sanjay Gandhi National Park',
    "lat": '19.2147067',
    "lng": '72.91062020000004',
    "description": 'Sanjay Gandhi National Park is a large protected area in the northern part of Mumbai city.'
}])';
```

**step 2:**

create a function that will pull that json object.

```
function getJsonString(){
return jsonString;
}
```

**step 3:**

pull any objects from your json with a dot notation. If you don't know how, I will edit my answer to add it, but it's pretty searchable and findable if you google ;) Let me know if this works, buddy.

Comment: i created a function getJsonString but it does not return the array as i need in my example ,please see the function on the code that i added as see where i did wrong?